# How to add png image to my ReadMe file on Github?

Tags: png, readme

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8QPk.png) The picture is not showing on my Readme file, only the link as shown in the photo. [photo itself not showing, only the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj32F.png)

I tried using html syntax instead, tried creating a new issue and copying the URL, also tried to just drag and drop directly to the readme file, nothing worked. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
![Sin titulo](pictures/avatar.png) or ![Con titulo](pictures/avatar.png "titulo")
```

I tried with png image and it works for me

```
![Sin titulo](https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first two didn't work for me. Not sure if wrote the last suggestion in the correct form or not. Will add a photo in my original post, for some reason, I'm not able to add it here.

Comment: I can't upload images either but in this link I attach the example https://imgur.com/vylS7MK

Comment: I saw your comment just now, you have the image locally try: './output_data/Fig1.png'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).